# Split string into multiple rows with one character each

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to split a word in a column into multiple rows, each with a single character. Small example below:

```
Id           Name          StartDate          EndDate
1            raj           2017-07-05          2008-08-06
```

here the expected result is:

```
Id           Name          StartDate          EndDate
1            r           2017-07-05          2008-08-06
1            a           2017-07-05          2008-08-06
1            j           2017-07-05          2008-08-06
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the string into a list and then use `explode`. Note that `filter` need to be used as otherwise one row will have an empty string.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1, "raj"), (2, "test"))).toDF("Id", "Name")
val df2 = df.withColumn("Name", explode(split($"Name", ""))).filter($"Name" =!= "")
```

This will give you:

```
+---+----+
| Id|Name|
+---+----+
|  1|   r|
|  1|   a|
|  1|   j|
|  2|   t|
|  2|   e|
|  2|   s|
|  2|   t|
+---+----+
```

Note, for older versions of Spark (older than 2.0.0), use `!==` instead of `=!=` when checking for inequality.

Comment: While creating df2, I am getting error like this.scala> val df2=df.withColumn("Name",explode(split($"Name",""))).filter($"Name" =!= " ")
<console>:27: error: value =!= is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
         val df2=df.withColumn("Name",explode(split($"Name",""))).filter($"Name" =!= " ")                                                                                                                           so please can you help me about this. Here I am using Spark version 1.6.0

Comment: @RajVerma Try to use `!==` instead of `=!=`. `=!=` is for newer versions of spark.